# Use TaskCompletionSource with generic Type as parameter

Tags: c#, .net, refactoring, taskcompletionsource

I am currently refactoring a bit of code which has two extremly similar methods.
Both methods use a TaskCompletionSource with a bool on one side and a string on the other.

Now both of those methods have a bit of code that reads the Task of the respective TaskCompletionSource and awaits it afterwards.

Is there a way to refactor this codebit into a method where I can pass the TaskCompletionSource as a parameter with a generic Type, so that I can use it in both methods and thus reduce my code?

Simplified example code:

```cs
public void BoolMethod(){
    TaskCompletionSource<bool> boolTCS = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    Task? taskToAwait = null;
    
    [...do shared code...]
    taskToAwait = boolTCS.Task;
    [...do shared code...]
    await taskToAwait;
    
    
    [...do method specific code...]
}

public void StringMethod(){
    TaskCompletionSource<string> stringTCS = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
    Task? taskToAwait = null;
    
    [...do shared code...]
    taskToAwait = stringTCS.Task;
    [...do shared code...]
    await taskToAwait;
    
    
    [...do method specific code...]
}
```

How I thought it worked / What I tried:

```cs
public Task? DoSharedCode(TaskCompletionSource<T> tcs){
    Task? taskToAwait = null;
    
    [...do shared code...]
    taskToAwait = tcs.Task;
    [...do shared code...]
    return taskToAwait;

}

public void StringMethod(){
    TaskCompletionSource<string> stringTCS = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
    
    await DoSharedCode(stringTCS);
    
    [...do method specific code...]
}
```

This gets me an [Error CS1503](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs1503?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS1503));

Could anyone tell me if this is possible and if yes, what I did wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a generic type you need to declare the type in the method or class, i.e:

```
public Task? DoSharedCode<T>(TaskCompletionSource<T> tcs){
    Task? taskToAwait = null;
    
    [...do shared code...]
    taskToAwait = tcs.Task;
    [...do shared code...]
    return taskToAwait;

}
```

But if you are not using the result from the task, why use different types for your `TaskCompletionSource`? Where do you set the task completion source result? Why create the intermediate `taskToAwait` instead of just `return tcs.Task`? The posted example do not make a lot of sense to me as it is.

Comment: Thanks that solved my problem. To your question, the original code makes way more sense than this but I had to remove quite a lot of it because of company policy. I tried to leave just enough code to show my problem with the generic type.